# Relating routing and navigation styles with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

Say you have a basic router set up in Angular as follows:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        redirectTo: "/news"
    }).when('/news', {
        templateUrl: "partials/pages/news.html",
        controller: "NewsCtrl"
    }).when('/about', {
        templateUrl: "partials/pages/about.html",
        controller: "AboutCtrl"
    })
});
```

And then you have an `index.html` that looks like:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#/news" class="active">news</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/about">about</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section ng-view></section>
```

What's the best way to add the `.active` class to the link corresponding to the route? Create a controller for the navigation? Use `$rootScope`? Etc. I'm having a problem with both those options, as neither seems very clean when I implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I use next code:

```
<ul class="navigation">
  <li ng-class="{active : (current == '/')}"><a href="/"><span>Articles</span></a></li>
  <li ng-class="{active : (current == '/about')}"><a href="/about"><span>About</span></a></li>
  <li ng-class="{active : (current == '/contact')}"><a href="/contact"><span>Contact</span></a></li>            
</ul>
```

In JS:

```
app.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function($location, $rootScope, $document) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
        $rootScope.current = $location.path();
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Simple, and it works for general cases. Something like this though starts to fall apart if you have a route like `/news/:id`, no? And if you're viewing a news article, it would make sense to still indicate you're on the news page with the `.active` class.

Comment: Yes, it's a problem. I temporary solve this by $rootScope.current = "/" + $location.path().split("/")[1]; But this solution is toooooooo far from good solution. Still waiting for effective solution.

Comment: Sounds like we're in the same boat. Easiest solution (though convoluted) I've come up with is to keep track in `$rootScope` the current nav item to be highlighted, and then every controller that relates to a nav item would change `$rootScope`. I'm sure there's something better though.